# Cannot create a scheduler job without a schedule

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've been trying to set up a schedule for a pub-sub function, depending on the environment I want to deploy, the process I'm following is simply adding those cron string parameters as environment variables.

.env.dev:

```
CRON_4H=every 4 hours
CRON_12H=every 12 hours
CRON_24H=every 24 hours
```

And use that parameter on the function definition

```
exports.myfunction = functions.pubsub.schedule(process.env.CRON_12H)
.onRun(context => {
// ETC
});
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot create a scheduler job without a schedule

```
{
  "id": "myfunction",
  "project": "----",
  "region": "----",
  "entryPoint": "----",
  "platform": "gcfv1",
  "runtime": "nodejs16",
  "scheduleTrigger": {
    "schedule": "",
    "timeZone": null
  },
  "labels": {
    "deployment-tool": "cli-firebase"
  },
  "availableMemoryMb": 512,
  "timeoutSeconds": 300,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "MIN_INSTANCES_1": "0",
    "MIN_INSTANCES_3": "0",
    "MIN_INSTANCES_5": "0",
    CRON_4H=every 4 hours,
    CRON_12H=every 12 hours,
    CRON_24H=every 24 hours,
    "FIREBASE_CONFIG": "--------",
  "codebase": "default",
  "securityLevel": "SECURE_ALWAYS"
}
```

it seems like the env vars are empty by the time of deployment, schedule and timezone indeed are empty, any advice on this?

EDIT:
seems like I'm setting runtime env vars, how can I define build environment vars for a firebase function?

Comment: Are you placing those env variables in a separated .env file as per the [docu](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env)?

Comment: You can define the firebase environment variables in an [env.json](https://dev.to/rajeshkumaravel/google-firebase-functions-setting-and-accessing-environment-variable-1gn2) file and you can use the following command to deploy i, ‘firebase functions:config:set env="$(cat env.json)"’

Comment: @Chris32 yes sir! .dev.env, env.prod, etc the problem relies on those are runtime vars I guess and not build vars so the vars are empty values

Comment: @pedrommuller Is this issue resolved now?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav I decided to go with a different approach and not use env vars at all

Comment: @pedrommuller can you post it as an answer , what have you done to resolve the issue, it would be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to set "build" variables, the only var I can use at that time was the project ID based on the firebase config which seems available during "build", so I changed the approach to the following:

In its own JS file to be imported:

```
    let envProjectId = ''
    if (process.env && process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG) {
        envProjectId = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId
    }

    exports.instances =
        envProjectId !== 'prod-projectI-id'
            ? {
                    MIN_INSTANCES_1: 0,
                    MIN_INSTANCES_3: 0,
                    MIN_INSTANCES_5: 0,
              }
            : {
                    MIN_INSTANCES_1: 1,
                    MIN_INSTANCES_3: 3,
                    MIN_INSTANCES_5: 5,
              }
```

it's not as elegant as putting all those vars into a proper env file but worked for me.